# how to find number for percentile in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I have a dataframe called df

```
df['value'] has values like (10,9,6,1,6,6,5,12,8,17,10,6,......,10,19,6,18,11)
```

I want to find the number that mark the 69.1% of the data

I managed to find this

```
df['value'].describe(percentiles=np.linspace(0, 1, 101))
```

which gives me each percent value, except i want it for 0.1 percent and I dont think 
I want to find that

```
df['value'].describe(percentiles=np.linspace(0, 1, 1001))
```

is practical, I wonder if there is another direct way to get the number that marks a certain percentage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` has a built-in function for this, so you can just do `df['value'].quantile(0.691)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.Series.quantile`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([10,9,6,1,6,6,5,12,8,17,10,6,10,19,6,18,11])
# sample series
s.quantile(0.691, 'nearest')
```

Output:

```
10
```